# Can't send emails from crontab to multiple dynamic address

Tags: cakephp, amazon-ec2, cron

I am trying to send some reminder emails to the users of the site. I have setup in Amazon EC2 and CakePHP as a language. I have a bit of code in CakePHP Shell which send the mail to particular recipients. I tried to setup as a cronjob.

My cronjob is working but sending the mail to /var/spool/mail/ec2-user instead of original recipients. I know I can send emails to multiple email addresses using MAILTO="..." in crontab but that all would be static addresses. Though my code has the email address of users of the website (remainder of payment in every 2 days) but still mail is being forwarded to /spool/mail/.

How do I setup the cronjob to send emails to dynamic email addresses or bound cronjob to send the email to the same recipient mentioned in CakePHP code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share what you have so far? As far as i know you can rhn php as a command in the shell - so you could cron a php script to be executed

Comment: @Jan that's true, I can call php script via crontab. but it is somewhat different issue as I have to call CakePHP controller function (to send emails) from crontab, which I have done. but when crontab calls the function, it fetches some emails for database and try to send emails to specified email addresses but couldn't send email to specified addresses instead in send mail to /spool/mail of user.